# Loading selected fields from a xml to listview

Tags: java, android, xml, listview

I want a method to populate a `listView` with data from an `xml` but with the fields that has a specific `tag`.

example:

```
<country continent="Asia" name="India" population="1.267b"/>    
<country continent="South America" name="Brazil"population="200.4m"/>
<country continent="Asia" name="Pakistan" population="182.1m"/>
```

From these fields I want to show only the countries that are in the **Asian continent**.

Thanks in advance.

[EDIT]
Here is some of the code I use,

```
CountryParser countryParser = new CountryParser ();
InputStream inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.countries);


// Parse the inputstream
countryParser.parse(inputStream);

// Get Countries
List<Country> countryList= countryParser.getList();


// Create a customized ArrayAdapter
CountryArrayAdapter adapter = new CountryArrayAdapter(
             getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.layout.listitem, countryList);

// Get reference to ListView holder
ListView lv = (ListView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.listView);

// Set the ListView adapter
lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: Have you tried using xpath ? `/tag/country[@continent="Asia"]`

Comment: `I want a method` Unfortunately, this is not how Stack Overflow works. Please, post your attempts, and tell us what doesn't work, why, what is the expected behaviour and what you are getting instead, so that we are able to help you find and correct the issue

Comment: @KennethClark No i haven't.

Comment: Are you having issues with getting the nodes or adding to a list view ?

Comment: @KennethClark no, it works. I just want to know a method to implement something like xpath.

Comment: What is the Country object ? JaxB ?

Comment: Take a look at the android [XMLParser](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_xml_parsers.htm), filter by the country name in that and get what you want.